# Return matched-pair and the non-matched pair for each ID only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any help would be appreciated.

I have two sample tables here.

Table A:

```
ID |Name
123|REG
123|ERT
124|REG
124|ACR
```

Table B

```
ID |Name
123|REG
123|WWW
124|REG
124|ADR
```

Here is the simple join output and I will explain my question in the comments:

*Yes -- I want this row

*No -- I don't want this row

```
AID|Aname|BID|Bname
123|REG  |123|REG  --Yes-- Matched-pair for id '123'
123|ERT  |123|REG  --No--'REG' already had one match. 'ERT' should pair with 'WWW' for id '123'
123|REG  |123|WWW  --No--The same reason as above
123|ERT  |123|WWW  --Yes--non-matched pair for id '123'
124|REG  |124|REG
124|ACR  |124|REG
124|REG  |124|ADR
124|ACR  |124|ADR
```

My desired result:

```
AID|Aname|BID|Bname
123|ERT  |123|WWW
123|REG  |123|REG
124|REG  |124|REG
124|ACR  |124|ADR
```

SQL server 2017.

Thank you in advance.

---

My approach (Inspired by the post from @The Impaler)

```
;with CTEall as(
select A.id as AID, A.NAME as Aname, b.id as BID,b.NAME as Bname  from A
inner join B on A.id = B.id),
match as (
select A.id as AID, A.NAME as Aname, b.id as BID,b.NAME as Bname  
from A inner join B on A.id = B.id and A.NAME = B.NAME)
select *
from CTEall 
where Aname not in (select Aname from match where AID = BID) 
and Bname not in (select Aname from match where BID = AID)
union all
select * from match
order by 1
```

Comment: What if there are two mismatches for one id in the second table?

Comment: @SalmanA there will only be one mismatch in the second table.

Comment: @GenWan Will there be more rows of the same ID from one table or the other?

Comment: @alans No, there will not be more rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often when you think about the logic you want in a different way, the answer (or at least AN answer) becomes obvious.

I am thinking of your logic this way:

> JOIN Table A to Table B such that A.ID=B.ID (always) AND EITHER
>   A.Name=B.Name OR A.Name doesn't have a Match in B, and B.Name doesn't
>   have a match in A.

This logic is pretty easy to express in SQL

```
WHERE a.ID=b.ID 
AND (
  a.Name=b.Name OR (
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB b2 WHERE b2.ID=a.ID AND b2.Name=a.Name)
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableA a2 WHERE a2.ID=b.ID AND a2.Name=b.Name)
  )
)
```

Comment: Here is a db<>fiddle for this solution:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4b53f04e15c3ea417841f8759dbb514.

Comment: The example data does not include the case for multiple unmatched rows on each side. In this case, this answer produces a cross join on them.

Comment: @TheImpaler that's because in a comment, the questioner says  "there will only be one mismatch in the second table."

Comment: Ugh, didn't see that one. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
with
m as ( -- matched rows
  select a.id as aid, a.name as aname, b.id as bid, b.name as bname
  from table_a a
  join table_b b on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
),
l as ( -- unmatched "left rows"
  select a.id, a.name,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by name) as rn
  from table_a a
  left join table_b b on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
  where b.id is null
),
r as ( -- unmatched "right rows"
  select b.id, b.name,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by name) as rn
  from table_b b
  left join table_a a on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
  where a.id is null
)
select aid, aname, bid, bname from m
union all
select l.id, l.name, r.id, r.name
from l
join r on r.id = l.id and r.rn = l.rn
```

**Note**: This solution may be a little bit overkill, since matches all unmatched rows when there are multiple ones per `ID`... something that is not necessary. Per OP comments there always be a single unmatched row per `ID`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I think there is something wrong after 'union all'. I don't think you can select r.id, r.name in the last select

Comment: My bad. Fixed last line to use `r` instead of `m`.

Comment: Your post inspired me. I will add my approach to the question summary.